# Yarn Application History Shows a Running Job but I can't find it

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

My Amazon EMR console under "Application History" shows some Yarn application is running:

Application ID: application_1562008xxxxxx_xxxx
Type: Spark
Action: PySparkShell .
Type: Running

but when I run

```
    yarn job -list
```

or

```
    hadoop job -list
```

I can't find any running job. Can someone explain what is happening here and how I can kill this job if it is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kill the application

```
Yarn application -kill [applicationID]
```

Answer (score 1):

it is probably

```
    yarn application -list
```